# No sound in Wesnoth

Tags: sound, games

I can install *The Battle for Wesnoth* by running

```
sudo apt-get install wesnoth
```

but when I start the game there is no music.  Everything else works fine gameplay wise, but it is silent.

How can I get sound in my Wesnoth installation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The music files have to be installed separately with

```
sudo apt-get install wesnoth-music
```